# Got nothing when using Foo.fromData to parse json

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a user by getting firebase JSON data using from data/ fromJson method. The program does not return a value nor it prints the next line for debugging.

```
      Future getUser(GUser user) async {
    try {
      
      print("getting user from ${user.id}");
      var fusr = await _usersCollectionReference.doc(user.id).get();
      print(fusr.data());
      GUser mainUser = GUser.fromData(fusr.data());
      print("GG");

    } catch (e) {
      if (e is PlatformException) return e.message;

      return e.toString();
    }
  }
```

In debug console `fusr.data()` is printed but "GG" is not printed and `mainUser` did not receive any data.
I have used a similar type of function in another code but didn't know why it is not working here.
Kindly help me get this issue solved.

```
    class GUser {
      final String id;
      final String fullName;
      final String email;
      final String picUrl;
      final double bal;
      final double rpl;
      final double upl;
      final List<Positon> position;

      GUser(
          {this.id,
          this.fullName,
          this.email,
          this.picUrl,
          this.bal,
          this.upl,
          this.rpl,
          this.position});

      GUser.fromData(Map<String, dynamic> data)
          : id = data['id'],
            fullName = data['fullName'],
            email = data['email'],
            picUrl = data['picUrl'],
            bal = double.parse(data['bal']),
            rpl = double.parse(data['rpl']),
            upl = double.parse(data['upl']),
            position = [data['position']];
```

Comment: Can you share the print output of fusr.data pls?

Comment: {upl: 1500, picUrl: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AATXAJzjjIMSDTht0cgs-Wgrcqpy2FfA4YzHvShP1f=s96-c, fullName: bunty kothekar, id: 8UTXUb1vdwFjgHjzdUCHpYEsX2, position: null, bal: 120000, email: buntykothekar@gmail.com, rpl: 150}